# How to select a value from comma seperated string inside an inner join query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, csv, join

I have joined a table and a view inside a procedure like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
NEW(V_IN IN VARCHAR2, V_PATH 
 OUT VARCHAR2)IS
   BEGIN
     FOR ITEM IN(SELECT 
     V.A||'\'||T.B INTO 
     V_PATH FROM TABLE1 T 
     INNER JOIN VIEW1 V ON 
     V.ID= T.FID WHERE 
     T.FID IN(--LOGIC TO 
     GET ONE INPUT FROM A 
     COMMA SEPERATED 
     STRING))
```

Here the IN variable V_IN is a comma seperated string. What I want to do is print the path of a file (like`abc\def.txt`) from a table and a view which are joined using an inner join. But how do I make the query recognize one value at a time if my input is like `('xyz','abc','',''...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the hierarchy query like follows:

```
T.FID in (
            SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                V_IN , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
              FROM DUAL CONNECT BY
                LEVEL <= 1 + REGEXP_COUNT(V_IN , ',')
        )
```

Comment: is there a similar way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea as I have never used SQL server.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your quick response.